# Вывести текст в input

Tags: javascript

Есть такой select

```
<select id="selectConfig1">
  <option value="100:первая опция">
  <option value="200:вторая опция">
</select>
```

И есть такой инпут

```
<input type="text" id="kod" name="kod" value="10:0:0:0:0">
```

Я написал код, который бы менял 10 в инпуте на значение из селекта:

```
const
  
  config1 = document.getElementById('selectConfig1'),
  kod = document.getElementById('kod');


   function setValue1 (){
    const config1V = config1.value.split(":"); /*значение из селекта */
    kodV = kod.value.split(":"); /*массив всех ячеек инпута */ 
    kod1V = kodV[0]; /* первая ячейка */
    kod1V.innerText = config1V[0].innerText; /*по идее ячейка с 10 должна поменяться на значение из инпута */
    
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setValue1);
config1.addEventListener('change', setValue1);
```

Но оно не работает, инпут выводит такое

Как пофиксить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Я написал код, который бы менял 10 в инпуте на значение из селекта:" Значение `config1V[0] === "100"` у  `kod1V  ===  10` Какой `kod1V.innerText = config1V[0].innerText` ? Ты бы вывел переменные в консоль, да посмотрел, что вообще пишешь..

Comment: @Rudi Я их выводил в консоль уже. В селекте 100, в инпуте 10.  Всё со значениями верно. Но как тогда 10 поменять на 100? Я пробовал innerText, innerHTML, но не получается

Comment: Откуда вообще у 100 и 10 может появиться innerText или innerHTML?

Comment: Я пробовал даже просто   kod1V = config1V[0] и оно всё равно не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заменить значения править @Rudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так можно сделать.. Где у тебя строка `kod1V.innerText = config1V[0].innerText;` можно переписать так `10.innerText = 100.innerText` а так быть не может.. Названия переменных в твоём примере, вносят путаницу ИМХО.

```js
let select = document.getElementById('сonfig1');
let inp = document.getElementById('inp');


function setValue1() {
  let selectVal = select.value.split(":"); /*значение из селекта */
  let inputVal = inp.value.split(":"); /*массив всех ячеек инпута */
  inputVal[0] = selectVal[0]; /* первая ячейка */
  inp.value = inputVal.join(":"); /*ячейка с 10 меняется на значение из инпута */
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setValue1);
select.addEventListener('change', setValue1);
```

```html
<select id="сonfig1">
  <option value="100:первая опция">
    <option value="200:вторая опция">
</select>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="kod" value="10:0:0:0:0">
```